# How can I install Windows XP from a USB drive?

Tags: windows, installation

I have image file of Windows XP installation and I need to know how to create a 
bootable USB drive with it so I can install Windows XP?

I am currently using a Linux operating system.

Comment: Are you asking how you create a bootable image of Windows XP on a USB drive?

Comment: yes I mean not with CD , I want to install from USB ?

Comment: Google "Hiren's boot disk"... There's one on there.

Comment: While what you want to do is possible, you do understand, the installation will only work on a single pc once it is activated. Windows XP does NOT support being moved to different PCs, the license does not support this, so a valid unused unactivated license is required to do this.  This question has been asked an answered http://superuser.com/questions/30530/can-i-boot-and-run-windows-xp-from-a-usb-flash-memory-stick

Comment: is it possible to made from linux ?

Comment: Are you trying to install Windows on a USB drive, or put the Windows installer on a USB drive so you can install it on a computer?

Comment: @Taegost - He is trying to install Windows XP on a USB device then boot to that device.

Comment: @Ramhound - His first comment says "I want to install from USB", which is why I'm a bit confused...  It sounds to me like you said, but then there's that.

Comment: I want to install Windows XP in my PC from A USB drive. Hope that clears

Comment: @Taegost - "what is the way of creating a Live USB with windows xp" clearly indicates he wants to make a Bootable Windows XP USB device.

Comment: @Jai - Yes thank you, that clears it up beautifully, so now we can get you the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `WinUSB`.

> WinUSB is a simple tool that enable you to create your own usb stick
>   windows installer from an iso image or a real DVD. This package
>   contains two programs: - WinUSB-gui: a graphical interface which is
>   very easy to use. - winusb: the command line tool.

To install in Ubuntu, run the following commands in Terminal:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install winusb
```

[image]

<sub>Note: This works for Windows Vista and up. ("Supported images: Windows Vista, Seven, 8 installer for any language and any version (home, pro...) and Windows PE.")</sub>

Comment: I heard that Winusb can work for only Windows 7 and Windows 8 there os. no support for xp.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/151073/how-to-create-windows-xp-liveusb-using-ubuntu-to-replace-it/192111#192111

Comment: @Jai: My sorry, see if this response answers your question:http://askubuntu.com/a/46629.

Comment: just now i made USB of windows XP but my bad is its not booting for installation process, the screen of unetbootin staying for ever

Answer (score 0):

I think Virtual Box or VM Ware is way to go.
It enables you to install multiple Operation Systems in one machine, without ever effecting each other. The OS run in completely isolated environment. You don't need to make any partition for the installation of OS in virtual box.

If you want to make a live USB stick, there are many software to use. For example [UNETBOOTIN](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/%E2%80%8E), which is pretty famous among my circle.
This software can even download ISO files from the internet, if you don't have the iso file. But there are still many alternatives. You can see the list [here](http://www.pendriveapps.com/software/live-usb/). They're all portable software, from PenDriveApps . com