# Installing Windows 7 to a thumb drive

Tags: windows-7, installation, usb-flash-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Windows OS (Windows 7) on a removable USB hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/17880/can-i-install-windows-os-windows-7-on-a-removable-usb-hard-drive)

I tried to seek but did not find.

just wanna know if someone here has tried installing Windows 7 ON a thumb (USB) drive.

am not talking about copying the whole Windows 7 installer on a USB drive and installing from there. i had seen how that works. I wanna know how one can install Windows 7 to a portable drive, and have your own Windows 7 on the go.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried myself, but from what I read it has been done.

The computer has to be able to boot from an USB drive, which isn't always supported on older models. Usually you have to edit the BIOS settings to enable it as the default commonly is to only boot from hard drive and CD/DVD drive.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it doesn't seem possible to boot win7 from a USB drive. There are a lot of complications within the OS that need to be dealt with. There are fixes for windowsXP to do this so I expect similar fixes for win7 in the future.

So if you want a booting USB drive you have to go with a Linux distibution or windowsXP.