# How can I Install a fresh copy of Windows XP or windows 7 into USB flash

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, windows-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Windows XP from USB pen drive](https://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-from-usb-pen-drive)
>   [Persistent install of Windows 7 (or XP) on a USB stick](https://superuser.com/questions/141156/persistent-install-of-windows-7-or-xp-on-a-usb-stick)
>   [Can I run Windows XP from a USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/254209/can-i-run-windows-xp-from-a-usb-flash-drive)

How can I Install a fresh copy of Windows XP or windows 7 into USB flash drive or a USB external Hard disk & use it independently in any PC & Laptops???

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I run Windows XP from a USB flash drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/254209/can-i-run-windows-xp-from-a-usb-flash-drive) and [Persistent install of Windows 7 (or XP) on a USB stick](http://superuser.com/questions/141156/persistent-install-of-windows-7-or-xp-on-a-usb-stick)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for some people, but this is by no means the intended use. If Windows detects that you are trying to install it onto a USB flash drive it will most likely prompt an error and abort.

However there seems to be possible according to [this guide](http://tech.gaeatimes.com/index.php/archive/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive/) with a software called 'NT 6.x fast installer' and a little known [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8it0NRqmKWU) demonstrating its use. Again, this is not by no way intended and you might run into some peculiar bugs and errors.

Remember to take back-up when handling with formatting of drives and the best of luck!