# How to install Windows 7 to an USB HDD from Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, usb

I'm trying to install Windows 7 from a CD to a HDD connected via USB. Windows complaints about not being able to install itself to USB-connected drives. All guides I found involve downloading a set of files from Microsoft, which include a .bat I should run. However, I only have Linux installed.

Is there a way to install Windows 7 to the HDD without having Windows installed somewhere else in the first place?

Comment: Maybe an option would be to remove the HDD from the USB case and replacing the current linux disk. You then can install onto that HDD, after installation exchange the drives and put the windows HDD back into the USB case.

Comment: Windows doesn't like being installed to USB drives, and takes some finagling to get it working. See the duplicate I marked: [Can I install Windows OS (Windows 7) on a removable USB hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/17880/can-i-install-windows-os-windows-7-on-a-removable-usb-hard-drive)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Apparently that answer only works for an entire disk installation... It seems the only way would be to crack open the case and pray for a SATA port to be there... So... No Windows, I guess.

Comment: You're best bet (as pointed out by answers in that dupe) is probably to just use a VM, and stick the VM files and it's virtual disks on the USB drive.